# sh: can't access tty: job control turned off

Tags: linux, boot, laptop

I have a Dell Precision P3551 built to run Linux (shipped with Ubuntu).
After the battery was replaced I tried to boot up the computer.
Pressed F12 after the Dell logo pops up and selected the drive to boot from. The grub menu comes up, I enter my encryption key then get sent to

blah blah blah
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off.

The drive is there because I get the screen to enter my encryption key.
I thought to just reinstall Arco but the nvme drive doesn't show up from any install usb?

I'm totally clueless as to what to do. I'd just assume nuke the drive because I know how to get everything back. But I see no way to do even that.

Comment: There a chance the firmware (UEFI) settings changed, somehow. The first thing you should check is drive/SATA mode (or something similarly worded). It should be AHCI, not "RAID" or Intel RST. Change accordingly and try again.

Comment: That was it!  I reset the clock but never thought about that. Thnx!!!

Answer (score 0):

The firmware (UEFI) settings were changed due the battery replacement.

Among other settings you may want to check and change accordingly the Drive/SATA mode should be set to **AHCI** instead of "RAID" or Intel Rapid Storage Technology (AKA "Intel RST"). This modes aren't yet compatible with most Linux distros and the factory installed Ubuntu must have been prepared with AHCI, as usual.